# Error in scheduled tasks: 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured.'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I deployed my Django app on pythonanuwhere and want to add one file to scheduled tasks. But it gives me an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I tried this:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE', 'smsreminder.settings')
django.setup()
```

Result the same, but error in the line with django.setup()
Script in the file, which I want to execute:

```
import datetime

from django_common.auth_backends import User

from reminder.models import Remind

from twilio.base.exceptions import TwilioRestException

from twilio.rest import Client

def my_scheduled_job():

    content = Remind.objects.all()
    account_sid = "--------------------------"
    auth_token = "--------------------------"
    for smscontent in content:
        if smscontent.remind_date == datetime.today().date():
            tempusers = User.objects.filter(username=smscontent.author)
            for recipient in tempusers:
                try:
                    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
                    message = client.messages.create(
                        body="I just want to remind, that you have some task for today {date}: {task}. {time} is the deadline!".format(
                            date=str(smscontent.remind_date), task=str(smscontent.title),
                            time=str(smscontent.remind_time)),
                        to=str(recipient.username),
                        from_="+18568889437")
                    print(message.sid)

                except TwilioRestException:
                    pass
    return
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/remindmy/sms-reminder/reminder/cron.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django_common.auth_backends import User
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_common/auth_backends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/remindmy/.virtualenvs/remindervenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.co
nfigure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: While this is possible to run Django code inside a scheduled task the way you're trying to do it, there are multiple gotchas that you'd need to take care of (like making sure the path is set correctly, that the imports are in correct order, etc.), so it's advised to rather write a management command and run it as a scheduled task.

Comment: Here's a link to the Django docs on creating management commands, in case it's of use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same issue today:

As the error proposes

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.co
nfigure() before accessing settings.
```

SETTING**S**, not SETTING. Thus, you just need to update your initial code with the capital S

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'smsreminder.settings')
django.setup()
```